# Strange behaviour of php session_start() when javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

To describe my question, I'am write 3 simple scripts:

- index.php (start a session and show html link);
- index.js (contain link click handler, fetch data from fetch.php);
- fetch.php (start a session, send response).

When I click on a link, javascript send a request to fetch.php. As I understand cookie also send because 'same-origin' specify. I'am expecting to see in response session_id, but response is appear after 7-9 seconds with message `Failed to load response data`. Why it can happened?

PS. If I remove session_start() line from fetch.php, response return instantly.

PSS. If I replace fetch with jQuery.post, response return instantly too.

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/">request</a>
        <script src="/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
let a = document.querySelector('a');

a.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch('/fetch.php', {

        headers: { 

            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        body: JSON.stringify({

            data: 'data',
        }),
    }).then((response) => {

        console.log('Success');

    }).catch((errors) => {

        console.log('Error');
    });
});
```

fetch.php

```
<?php
session_start();

header('HTTP/1.1 200 Ok', true, 200);
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode(array(

    'id' => session_id(),
));
?>
```

Comment: Would the comma in your array not throw an error?

Comment: @Mouser No, scripts doesn't throw any error.

Comment: Check your server error logs, your script maybe erroring out and thus not printing anything, as otherwise you should be at least getting some json printout

Comment: What do you see in the console when you output `data`

Comment: @Mouser To check a response from fetch.php I'am using Chrome Developer Tools, in Response tab I see nothing (it is empty). It is only in session_start() problem, If I remove it from script, response send properly.

Comment: Drop the header and see if your response is 500

Comment: @Mouser Nothing in response, status code 200 even drop headers in fetch.php

Comment: @PatrickEvans Nothing in server error log.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is appear only in Chrome. The solution is to add intermediate json handler into fetch

```
}).then(function (response) {

    return response.json();

}).then(function (json) {

    console.log('Success');
    console.log(json);

}).catch(function (errors) {

    console.log('Error');
});
```

and problem pass away.

Comment: That would mean your response was not empty at all.

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes, as I understand Chrome doesn't show such response in Developer Tools. It is a Chrome bug.